# NSFetchedResultsController for UITableView scroll to top at insert change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is backed up by an `NSFetchedResultsController`. I wish to scroll to the top of the tableView hiding the search bar after a row as been inserted in the table, i.e.

```
-> row created
-> row inserted
-> row insert animation finished
-> **scroll to top hiding search controller**
```

The only way to know if a row has been aded is to look at the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` API `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `CATransaction` to get notified when `UITableView` finished animations:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        if(self.shouldScrollToTop) {
            [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        }
        self.shouldScrollToTop = NO;
    }];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [CATransaction commit];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ newIndexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            self.shouldScrollToTop = YES;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is pretty cool. My only issue is having CATransaction blocks in different code blocks. I might have other CATransition blocks elsewhere too.

Comment: @p0lAris you can try wrapping endUpdates in CATransaction. I don't think table view does anything before you call endUpdates. Also CATransactions can be nested I think, so you should be safe even if you have other transactions around.